# What determines whether you keep or lose ingredients after a failed synthesis?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've been leveling my Disciples of Hand classes (crafting) recently and I've noticed something odd. Usually when I fail a synthesis, I lose all the ingredients I had put into it. But every now and then, I've gotten those ingredients back. While I can figure out the reason for some the cases, like when I quit a synthesis without performing any steps, I can't determine the exact mechanics behind how I get a refund.

Answer (score 2):

There's a small chance that you will get your ingredients back whenever you fail a synthesis.

Exactly what influences this, IDK, however Culinarian has level 50 skill Reclaim that increases it to 90%

Do note that you only get those back if you FAIL the synthesis. Quitting synthesis will not give you your ingredients back unless you quit at Step 1 (before taking any action).

Comment: That can't be right as I've quit a synthesis without losing my materials, although I had quit at Step 1.

Comment: I've never tried to quit at step 1, I did try to quit at step 2 and never got my ingredients back. Actually, the chance of getting things back is kind of good, during my time I generally get back my ingredients when failing about 80% of the time. My buddy did say that quitting will not give your stuff back, and I never tried quitting ever since. If there's evidence that quitting = failing, I'll amend my statement

Comment: If you quit at the very first step (i.e. without taking an action) there is no penalty.  This is because it's easy to accidentally start the wrong synthesis and they don't want to penalize that.  Actually taking any actions indicates that it's what you want to craft and that's when the item loss kicks in.

Comment: Posting to confirm that quitting at Step 1 will return all ingredients, including your crystal. Easily reproducible by taking an inventory count before and after testing.